# What does '$' do in a git commit message?

Tags: php, bash, git

I was reviewing my `git log` and saw a commit message that didn't make sense.

It said: `Updated all  to use -> instead.` (note the double space in `all__to`)

When I ran `history` in my bash session, it shows:

> `641  git commit -m "Updated all $microsoftReference to use $this->$allMicrosoftIDs instead."`

So, either Git or Bash is interpretting the $ and

The app is PHP 8.1.0, so `$microsoftReference` is a variable and `$this` refers to a `$classObject->property`.

FWIW, I'm using Git Bash on Windoze 10.

Comment: Bash interprets variables in double-quoted strings, use single quotes instead, or escape your dollar signs with backslashes "\$"

Comment: Note that this is bog-standard bash behavior; it has nothing at all to do with Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: it was Bash interpreting the `$` but they did not translate to anything showing output so they showed as blanks in the final message.